# Zoom in on clicking a pin with multiple pins in close proximity without clustering

Tags: google-maps

I have multiple pins on my google map and some of them are in close proximity/overlapping one another. I don't want my pins to be cluster but I still want the effect where the map zoom in when user clicks on a pin that intercepts another.

Many of the solutions I found online suggested Clustering or OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier. I don't want to make any changes to my markers just the ability to zoom in.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible sample of your problem? This will increase the chances that your question will get answers since the sample will allow the community to properly investigate your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling a `map.setCenter` then `map.setZoom` with a click event on your marker.

Here is a sample fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pzc4aodt/

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151}
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
    map: map,
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(17);
  });
```